# Of all the planes that passes through $(2,1,1)$, find the one which is furthest away from the origin.

Tags: linear-algebra

Of all the planes that passes through $P=(2,1,1)$, find the one which is furthest away from $O=(0,0,0)$.

I know that the plane is $2x+y+z=6$, but I don’t understand why. 
I noticed that the normal vector of the plane is the one given by $P-O$ but why is that?
Wouldn’t that be finding the one which is closest?

Comment: *How* do you know that the plane that you are looking for is $2x+y+z=6$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Because that’s the solution given in the exam. What I’ll like to know is how to get there

Comment: because that's the answer @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: Consider a sphere centered at the origin where 2,1,1 is on the sphere. You want a plane tangent to that sphere at 2,1,1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider all the possible planes which pass through $P(2,1,1)$. If the plane is not perpendicular to the vector $\vec {OP}$, then it will be perpendicular at another point and this will be closer than $d=2^2+1^2+1^2=6$ units. Hence the plane will be furthest when the normal vector is $2\hat i+\hat j+\hat k$.

The equation of a plane is given by the formula $\vec r\cdot\hat n=d$
$$(x\hat i+y\hat j+z\hat k)\cdot\Biggr(\frac {2\hat i+\hat j+\hat k}{\sqrt {2^2+1^2+1^2}}\Biggr)=\sqrt {2^2+1^2+1^2}$$
$$2x+y+z=6$$

Comment: Thanks, but I’ve got a question. Why being perpendicular at another point implies that it’ll be closer?

Comment: @Facu50196 Think of a sphere centered at $(0,0,0)$ passing through P. The plane will be tangent to the line OP. But if we tilt the plane in any other direction, the new plane will become perpendicular at another point which will lie **inside** the circle. Hence the new plane will be closer to the origin.

Answer (score 2):

$\vec n \cdot (\vec r - (2,1,1))=0$.

Choose the normal : $\vec n =(2,1,1)$;

($\vec n$ is direction vector joining $(0,0,0)$ to $(2,1,1)$).

Then

$(2,1,1)\cdot (x-2,y-1,z-1)=0$;

$2(x-2)+(y-1)+ (z-1)=0$;

$2x+y+z-6=0$.

Reasoning:

Consider a sphere centered at origin with

radius  $R=\sqrt{2^2+1^1+1^1}$ passing through $(2,1,1)$.

With the above choice of $\vec n$  the plane lies in the tangential plane of the sphere at $(2,1,1)$, i.e. touches  the sphere.

Any other choice  of $\vec n$ will tilt the plane and have it intersect the sphere in other points, means: there are points on the plane within the sphere, smaller distance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to visualise the problem in two dimensions first: given a point $P\in\Bbb R^2$, what is the line through $P$ that is furthest from the origin? You ought to be able to convince yourself that this line is perpendicular to $OP$. Draw a picture if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In right angle triangle OQP right angle at Q . Hypotonous is OP is the longest side i.e $OP\ge OQ$ hence when distance is OP plane is at maximum distance.